# WPF C# Finding the corners of a transformed RectangleGeometry

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, collision

I'm trying to do some hit testing on a Rect I've drawn with several RenderTransforms pushed to the Canvas' DrawingContext. I've applied the same rotate/scale/translate transforms to a RectangleGeometry so I can get the bounds of the final drawing. However, the .Bounds property on RectangleGeometry returns the axis-aligned bounding box, while I need the oriented bounding box.

In short, I need some way to find the corners of the actual transformed rectangle so I can perform hit/collision testing on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the transforms to the points of the rectangle.

Comment: That worked perfectly. It's funny how obvious some solutions are once they're pointed out to you. Thanks.